# Super weird Solidity gas issue about conversion between calldata and memory

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, solc

Inconsistent gas usage for conversion of calldata to memory in external call and internal call. This is observed after 0.8.0. In 0.7.6, their gas usages are the consistent.

### Steps to Reproduce

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


contract Dummy {
    function iacceptmem(uint256[] memory amounts) internal {
    }
   
    function test1(uint256[] memory amounts) external {
        iacceptmem(amounts);
    }

    function test2(uint256[] calldata amounts) external {
        iacceptmem(amounts);
    }

}


contract Tester {
    Dummy d = new Dummy();

    function call_test1() external {
        uint256[] memory data = new uint256[](1000);
        d.test1(data);
    }

    function call_test2() external {
        uint256[] memory data = new uint256[](1000);
        d.test2(data);
    }
}
```

If you deploy Tester and call `call_test1` and `call_test2`, you will find that execution cost of `call_test2` is 295126, but `call_test1` is 517391. From yul, we can see they both have the conversion from calldata to memory once. But what is the difference is `call_test2` is converting before `iacceptmem` call, `call_test1` is converting at before executing the `test1`.

I tried on the Remix IDE, and dump the asm and YUL from solc, cannot figure out why